# try to center text whilst keeping style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

OK, I amusing bootstrap and have some thumbnail boxes with text inside (see code bellow).

I also wish to vertically and horizontally align the text, I have done this using `flexbox`, this seems to work, however now the `span`, `h4` and `p` tag are all on the same line rather than `stacked`.

whats the best way to fix this so i get the tags `stacked` but also center both horizontal and vertical.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3 overlord-thumbnail">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">
            <div class="caption">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <h4>Latest News</h4>
                <p>text here</p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <h4> Latest News</h4>
        <p>text here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlord-thumbnail {
    height: 188px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.thumbnail {
    background: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: inline-flex;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.caption {
    position:absolute;
    top:-100%;
    right:0;
    background: rgba(66, 139, 202, 0.64);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:2%;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff !important;
    z-index:2;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.thumbnail:hover .caption {
    top:0;
}
```

**currently**

[image]

**should be**

[image]

Comment: you want latest news, text here and icon in one row?

Comment: nope, i want them stacked as they would be without display: inline-flex;

Comment: @BenjaminOats  ..  See my answer, is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the default styles are overriding the styles you are applying. Use `.overlord-thumbnail>.thumbnail` to give it priority.

Also you need to use `flex-direction:column;` to get them stacked and not aligned in row next to each other.

```css
.overlord-thumbnail {
    height: 188px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.overlord-thumbnail>.thumbnail{
    background: whitesmoke;
    border-radius:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    text-align:center;
}

.caption {
    position:absolute;
    top:-100%;
    right:0;
    background: rgba(66, 139, 202, 0.64);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:2%;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff !important;
    z-index:2;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    
}
.thumbnail:hover .caption {
    top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 overlord-thumbnail">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">
                <div class="caption">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <h4>Latest News</h4>
                    <p>text here</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <h4> Latest News</h4>
            <p>text here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @BenjaminOats ...Oh, I think I got it wrong, I thought you were trying to center the text that comes on hover.

Comment: Ok it is centered now. I hope this is what you were trying to achieve. also please dont forget to accept and upvote the answer